# Why was I logged out of every Stack Exchange site tonight?

Tags: support, openid, login

I was suddenly dismissed from all the SE sites I've been logged into for months.  Since that's an unusual occurrence, I can't help but ask what happened?

Answer (score 2):

You might try checking the blog.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  However, after first logging into SO, I wasn't subsequently "automagically" logged into SU or SF.

Comment: @raven then you'll have to troubleshoot, if you want global auth. See the post for excruciating detail.